# Vehicle year that may contain the vehicle information provided by the witness

Tags: mysql, sql

For my CIS class, I have SQL project, I'm still very new to SQL and trying to learn it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Query: The collected evidence shows that the vehicle's color is white, the make is BMW, and some letters on the plate were remembered: there is three letter "C"s on the plate. 
Required:

1. Write a query to show all driver names and license_plate_number/vehicle_make/ vehicle year that may contain the vehicle information provided by the witness. Add attributes if necessary to complete the assignment.

I did the first part of this problem:

```
select driver_name as "Driver Name", license_plate_number as 
"License Plate Number", vehicle_make as "Make", make_year as "Year"  
from driver, license 
where driver.driver_id = license.driver_id
```

But for the second part I'm getting an empty return, I do not know what I'm doing wrong. This is what I tried:

```
select driver_name, license_plate_number, vehicle_make, make_year 
from driver, license 
where driver.driver_id = license.driver_id and 
license_plate_number like 'C%%CC%%' and  
vehicle_make = "BMW"  
and color = "white"
```

Comment: `and license_plate_number like '%C%C%C%'`

Comment: Stil getting an error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '1. select driver_name, license_plate_number, vehicle_make, make_year 2. from dr' at line 1  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d1836d/15

Comment: error you are getting on sqlfiddle is beacuse you have numbers 1. 2. 3. 4. 5. 6 in front of every row :)

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is with three letter "C"s on the plate.

The way you wrote `license_plate_number like 'C%%CC%%'` it would mean plate has to begin with C and double % are not necessary. % sign is replacement for any number of strings.

Correct condition for three letter "C"s ANYWHERE on the plate is :
`license_plate_number like '%C%C%C%'`

And while we are at it, please learn to use proper JOIN syntax. Style you are using is before SQL-92 standards, outdated 25 years ago.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)

```
SELECT d.driver_name, l.license_plate_number, l.vehicle_make, l.make_year 
FROM driver d
INNER JOIN license l ON d.driver_id = l.driver_id
WHERE l.license_plate_number like '%C%C%C%'
AND l.vehicle_make = "BMW"  
AND l.color = "white"
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d1836d/19

Comment: Thank you so much but our professor still hasn't touched on JOIN syntax.

Comment: follow what he said on his VERY FIRST COMMENT. you will be fine.